# Fan fiction where Harry Potter is allergic to a potion

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I’ve read a fic but I can’t remember what it was called where Harry is allergic to an ingredient in a potion and they only find out after a potion accident?

Sorry my memory is very bad so sorry for making people confused this is all I can remember.

Comment: "And they only find out..." after what? I feel like you're missing part of your sentence.

Comment: Even the most simplest of searches reveals several fanfics where Harry is allergic to a potion. Can you narrow this down? What else happens?

Answer (score 1):

Sound more like [Allergic to Potions, By: Cordria](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/8368857/1/Allergic-to-Potions)

> Harry found his mouth moving, but a burst of pain turned the words into something of a groan of agony. His eyes fluttered closed again, struggling to gain control of the sharp shards that were slicing into his mind.
>
> "Why, in Merlin's name, did you not tell anyone you were allergic to pallid grass?
>
> The man's voice drilled into Harry's brain, making the pain all the worse. Harry felt his body wince, his hand coming up to press against his skull. His fingers twitched, out of his control. His brain felt like it was two sizes too big for his head. A hiss worked its way out of his mouth.
>
> "I suppose you enjoy being in immense amounts of pain."

It was more due to not taking a vaccination.